# Changing environment variables

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, environment-variables

I just changed my `/etc/environment` file to:

```
M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
M2=$M2_HOME/bin
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
PATH=$M2:$PATH
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45
PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

(trying to do something similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275704/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables-path-and-m2-home-in-ubuntu-for-ma))

However, when I tried checking the environment variables by typing, for instance `echo "$M2"`, the result is an empty line for all the variables and $PATH is the same as before editing the file. Why didn't my changes operate? I tried closing and opening the shell, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/environment` takes a proper re-login to take effect, because it is processed by PAM at login. Further, as @przemo noted, it is not run or sourced as a script, so variables are not expanded. Put such variables in a `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d/`:

```bsh
sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/my_vars.sh <<"EOF"
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
EOF
```

This will also take a re-login to take full effect, but you can test it out immediately by running a login shell:

```
$ bash -l
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

As Gunnar has pointed out, the default assignment to `PATH` should remain in `/etc/environment`, and shouldn't be added to the above script. See [this community wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-profile.d.2BAC8.2A.sh) for more information.

Comment: I would have left the original PATH assignment in `/etc/environment` where it is located by default. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I saw the variables being set before PATH and thought OP may have modified it in some way.  So I copy-pasted that part. On closer examination, I agree, that looks like the default PATH and I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/environment` is not a script file, you cannot use variables, for further reading I recommend https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables