# How to set Maven home PATH on Ubuntu as User

Tags: java, environment-variables, maven-3

I am new to Ubuntu and Maven. Recently I installed Maven in my system as user and the installation went perfectly, but I can't set path environment variable permanently. I also referred to the following questions but I couldn't solve my problem.

[Maven environment variable not working on other terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747745/maven-environment-variable-not-working-on-other-terminal)

[How to permanently set environmental variables PATH and M2_HOME in ubuntu for maven3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275704/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables-path-and-m2-home-in-ubuntu-for-ma)

I can set `m2_home` path in my system as user but when I check if the path is set with `mvn -v` I get the following error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
```

When I restart the terminal I can't find the path of `M2_home`. I don't have root access.

Comment: Which one of shell you use? If bash, you can set environment variables via `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Linux based systems are case sensitive: `M2_HOME`, `m2_home` and `M2_home` are 3 different variables. Double check that

Comment: @EskanderBejaoui you are right it is case sensitive. there are gramer mistake in my question only not in command which i tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting the `M2_HOME` environment variable is no longer required if you're using Maven 3. The important thing is to have the `/bin` directory of you maven installation added to the `PATH` environment variable.

Anyway, personally I find that exporting the `M2_HOME` env variable makes reconfiguring the location easier at a later time if needed.

The actual error you're reporting is related to `JAVA_HOME` not being set correctly, but I'll get to that after setting up Maven.

First of all, to have `M2_HOME` set between terminal restarts you'll have to add the export statement to `~/.bashrc` (assuming your shell is bash). This will override any of these environment variables set system wide by `/etc/environment`

My Maven installation is located at `/opt/apache-maven-3.5.4`, so to add that to my `~/.bashrc` file I could do

```
echo 'export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.4' >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then I would utilize `M2_HOME` when I add maven to `PATH`, like so

```
echo 'export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now configure `JAVA_HOME` the same way. My java installation is located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java` but when configuring `JAVA_HOME` some of that path will need to be stripped away.

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then, if you start a new terminal you should be able to run `mvn -v` and get the desired result.

Comment: i just fourgot to tell that my java is perfactly running without any error...befour ant after maven installatin. but just maven not working

Comment: Could be, but the actual error message from Maven is that JAVA_HOME is not correctly defined. What is the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: it is give me path of java installed path

Comment: i just try this solution but after i exit terminal and restart terminal,after check `$M2_HOME` .....its not seted yet

Comment: thankyou and done....using this solution after root give some access....

Answer (score 1):

Setup Maven and Specific Java version for particular user on Ubuntu 16.04. Download Apache Maven 3.3.6, Java 1.8 and extract them to certain directories.
Do following steps:

1. open terminal and Go to Particular User
2. gedit ~/.profile
3. Add below lines 
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_251
   export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
   PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin"
4. Save the Changes
5. source ~/.profile

Then Run Command to verify 
mvn -version

It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

After Maven Install, If you doesn't accessible globally in Ubuntu 22. then you need to set exporting the M2_HOME env variable makes.

My Maven installation is located at /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3.

```
echo 'export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc
```

> **NOTE :-** after add path in `.bashrc` file you need to restart your terminal. then try run `mvn -version` command for verify

---

**OR**

Your can Manaully Add below 2 lines (exporting path) in `.bashrc` file

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

---

Additional Info : for JDK & Maven Installation steps you can follow [this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-maven-linux-ubuntu)