# Update info - how to currently set Java_home?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, bashrc, environment, maven-3

I'am trying to get Maven running. I have installed JDK and Maven.
Thus I have been trying to set the Java_home variable for three days now, I cannot get it working.

I have followed the instructions of another askUbuntu Topic:

- [How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)
- [How to set Maven home PATH on Ubuntu as User](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052131/how-to-set-maven-home-path-on-ubuntu-as-user)

This doesn't work. Not any explanation explains how to set the path, they rather give examples how to set their path.. So I have no idea whats wrong with mine, it is the location to the file in the etc/environment.

I installed maven by downloading the correct latest version on the site. Extracted and installed it in opt directory using known sudo-commands.

I created the maven.sh file myself, since there wasn't a file like this in the profile.d directory. You can see how I set that in the cat output and the picture below.

The Java_Home set in my `etc/environement` though is:
`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64";`This used to be `/usr/opt/jdk-13.0.1` (which you will see the terminal give back the first time), because thats how I thought It needed to work according to explanation how to install Maven.

When I source my maven.sh, I get the right mvn -version in the terminal. When I close terminal, I have to source it again.

Here my terminal feedback on the versions, rember that after the first 3 commands (version -java, -mvn and echo) I source my maven.sh file manually:

```
mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/opt/jdk-13.0.1

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.2 (ea98e05a04480131370aa0c110b8c54cf726c06f)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-27-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

mussche@MuskiProBook:~$ cat /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

`/etc/profile.d/maven.sh` content:

[image: /etc/profile.d/maven.sh]

How to install maven correct? How to set the variables, where to find the files that need to be changed, and exactly how to change them?

Comment: Is this the right version of the JDK for the version of Maven you have installed?

Comment: `/etc/environment` isn't a shell script, don't use `;` to end lines in it.

Comment: @MuskeYannick Can you share screenshot from IntelliJ? Also, did you mistype `environment` in question only or in terminal as well? Is `mvn` working when `JAVA_HOME` is set to Java 11? Also, please note that Java 13 was a non-LTS release and has reached its end of life.

Comment: @MuskeYannick You can upload image by clicking on [edit] button and hit Ctrl+G (if you're unable to find icon with picture while editing). Also, how did you install maven? Did you create `maven.sh` on your own? I also use maven, Java, Ubuntu and Eclipse/IntelliJ and didn't find any problems. I don't even set `JAVA_HOME` in my installation. So, you might want to edit your question to explain what and how you installed things and what exact problems you're facing with regards to Java/IntelliJ, redacting other things. Fo example, I don't think "*Dear Ubuntu....*" is relevant to the issue.

Comment: My 2 questions are still unanswered: 1. how did you install maven? and 2. Did you create `maven.sh` on your own? Let's check the current status of files. Please edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/environment` and `cat /etc/profile.d/maven.sh`.

Comment: Hey, Deleted previous posts to create more space. I've altered my question with more specific details as requested. The installation of Maven, I downloaded, extracted and installed in opt.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I don't exactly why, but after several restarts (not after just one) the path got set instantly instead of me having to manually source it.

Kr,

Yannick

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu - to add `Java-openJdk` and `Maven`

1. Install OpenJDK through CLI
2. Move `Maven` and `Gradle` to `/opt/`

### Working config for `openjdk-17`

`sudo vim /etc/profile`

```shell
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle-8.1
PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin

export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.9.1
PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

### I saw one restart required, then check `mvn --version`